# Recursively traverse a Json object in pure Swift

Tags: json, swift, recursion

Supposed to have a nested (valid) JSON structure like:

```
{
  "artists": {
    "offset": 0,
    "next": null,
    "href": "https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/search?query=tania+bowra&offset=0&limit=20&type=artist",
    "limit": 20,
    "previous": null,
    "total": 1,
    "items": [
      {
        "genres": [
        ],
        "images": [
          {
            "url": "https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/f2798ddab0c7b76dc2d270b65c4f67ddef7f6718",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 640
          },
          {
            "url": "https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/b414091165ea0f4172089c2fc67bb35aa37cfc55",
            "width": 300,
            "height": 300
          },
          {
            "url": "https:\/\/i.scdn.co\/image\/8522fc78be4bf4e83fea8e67bb742e7d3dfe21b4",
            "width": 64,
            "height": 64
          }
        ],
        "id": "08td7MxkoHQkXnWAYD8d6Q",
        "external_urls": {
          "spotify": "https:\/\/open.spotify.com\/artist\/08td7MxkoHQkXnWAYD8d6Q"
        },
        "popularity": 2,
        "followers": {
          "total": 25,
          "href": null
        },
        "href": "https:\/\/api.spotify.com\/v1\/artists\/08td7MxkoHQkXnWAYD8d6Q",
        "type": "artist",
        "name": "Tania Bowra",
        "uri": "spotify:artist:08td7MxkoHQkXnWAYD8d6Q"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to traverse this structure in pure `Swift` lang (no Apple `Cocoa` `Foundation` dependencies) in order to access each nodes to leafs recursively 
in order to apply a `block` closure defined like

```
closure : (key:String, value:AnyObject, list:[String:AnyObject])
```

where `list` argument will act like an `Accumulator`.

The output in the accumulator `list` must have the same structure of the input json:

```
var json:[String:AnyObject]! = [String:AnyObject]();
```

As example, I wrote a recursive closure in Swift, passing the `acc` as well. In this case I was just making a sum of a `[String:Int!]` `Swift.Dictionary`:

```
var closure:( ([String:Int!], acc:[String:AnyObject]) -> [String:Int!])!
closure = { (var x, var l) in
    if (x["value"] >= 10) {
        closure = nil;
        return x;
    } else {
        x["value"]=x["value"]!+1;

        return closure(x, acc:l)
    }
}

var list:[String:AnyObject]! = [String:AnyObject]();
let kv:[String:Int!] = [
    "value" : 0,
];
let value = closure(kv,acc:list)
print(value);
```

Comment: Why not use Foundation? It's actually [open source](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation) and runs on Linux just fine now, with a only few minor differences from the Mac Objective-C version.

Comment: I think because in 2016 it was different the foundation was not released yet and as far as ai remember it did not compile properly without ios libraries. Now this is not true anymore, so if you provide an answer I will be glad to accept it, thank you.